# Filter a column in a dataframe based on the name of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes that all contain a column that is the name of the data frame with underscores replaced with spaces and sans the last 3 characters.
['Player_Bio_df', 'Team_df', 'Rate_df']
For example

```
Player_Bio_df= pd.DataFrame({'field':['name','address','address2','city','state','zip','home','cell'],'Player Bio':[1,1,2,1,3,1,2,1]})

Team_df = pd.DataFrame({'field':['name','address','address2','city','state','zip','home','cell'],'Team':[1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2]})

Rate_df= pd.DataFrame({'field':['name','address','address2','city','state','zip','home','cell'],'Rate':[1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1]})
```

I also have a list (of strings) of all the dataframe names (SelFieldsDfs below).

```
 SelFieldsDfs  = ['Player_Bio_df', 'Team_df', 'Rate_df']
```

I want to filter so all the dataframes such that Team_df only has the records that has address2 and home  in 'Field' (because Player Bio = 2 in those same records). Rate_df would only have the records address2, state, home, and cell, since Rate = 2 int hose records

so I to filter this list of dataframes on that specific field for the value 2

```
 for dfs in SelFieldsDfs:
     colname = str(dfs).replace('_', ' ')[:-3]
     vars()[str(dfs)] = str(dfs)[str(dfs).colname == 2]
```

The error says 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'colname''

Comment: what does `str(dis)` evaluate to?

Comment: It's a string list of 12 dataframes: ['Player_Bio_df', 'Team_df', 'Rate_df'] etc. Then each of those dataframes has a column like Player Bio, Team, Rate, etc.

Comment: updated a typo and elaborated the error

Comment: you're operating on a string like it's a dataframe and that's not going to work. you don't want to access variables by their name in python. at best, you put them into a dictionary.

Comment: in your example, you have the individual dataframe in your as `dfs`. operate on it directly

Comment: Could you explain the filter? There will be the dataframes with it's variable name as second column? I mean, with 'Player_Bio_df', the second column it's 'Player Bio'?

Comment: correct the second column will be Player Bio

Comment: Ready, just added an approach @Jogianni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it's because you are trying to use an string (`dfs`) as a dataframe in this line:

```
vars()[str(dfs)] = str(dfs)[str(dfs).colname == 2]
```

But, you need to get and change the value of the dataframe name, so change that line to this:

```
vars()[dfs]= vars()[dfs][vars()[dfs][colname]==2]
```